# Tight upper bound for $\sum_{i=1}^{d} \log_{2} (c_{i})$ where $d>0, c_{i}>0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{d}c_{i} \leq n$

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, computer-science

I would like to bound the above summation by something that is not dependent on $d$. One trivial upper bound would be to say that it is $O(d\log_{2} (n))$. If we change the summation so that it is $\sum_{i=1}^{d} c_{i}$ then the bound becomes $O(n)$ no matter how big $d$ is. Since $\log_{2}(x) < x$ for all $x>0$ we can also bound the original summation by $O(n)$. Can we do better than $O(n)$? Can we actually bound it by $O(\log n)$?

Comment: The logarithm is concave. Check out [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality).

Comment: And BTW, don't use $*$ for multiplication in mathematics. Its meaning is convolution, not multiplication. If you really need a multiplication sign, use `\cdot` (which renders as $\cdot$). You didn't need one here, so I just deleted the asterisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to use natural logarithms instead. You can divide by $\ln 2$ at the end of the calculation.

First, by Jensen's inequality,
$$
\frac1d\sum_{i=1}^d\ln c_i\le\ln\Bigl(\frac1d\sum_{i=1}^d c_i\Bigr) .
$$
Multiplying by $d$ and using the assumption, we get
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^d\ln c_i\le d\ln\frac nd .
$$
For any given $n$, this is sharp, since putting $c_i=n/d$ turns the inequality into an equality.

You want an estimate independent of $d$, so take the maximum value of the RHS when $d$ varies. Using standard calculus methods, you find that this happens when $d=n/e$. This might not be an integer, but never mind – when $n$ is large, rounding off to the nearest integer will not change the answer much.
The resulting estimate is going to be
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^d\ln c_i\le \frac ne.
$$
This is not sharp for any fixed $n$, due to the stated rounding issues – but asymptotically, as $n\to\infty$, it should be quite sharp.